# React with Greensock - Please gsap.registerPlugin(CSSPlugin, CSSRulePlugin)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, gsap

I'm trying to do a reveal image effect with Greensock and React.js but i'm getting a warning related to the CSS Plugin.

First of all, i need to get the rule of the pseudo element that i want to animate for the reveal effect

```
  const imageReveal = CSSPluginRule.getRule("#image-container:after");
```

And the next step is to animate the width

```
 tl.to(container.current, 1, { css: { visibility: "visible" } }).to(
      imageReveal,
      1.5,
      { css: { width: "0%", ease: Power2.easeIn } }
    );
```

The animation is not working and i'm wondering if the problem is because of this warning:

```
Please gsap.registerPlugin(CSSPlugin, CSSRulePlugin)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is occurring because you did not import and register CSSRulePlugin, just as the warning says. You do not have to register CSSPlugin because it's part of GSAP's core. To import and register CSSRulePlugin, include the following at the top of your script:

```
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { CSSRulePlugin } from "gsap/CSSRulePlugin";

gsap.registerPlugin(CSSRulePlugin);
```

I *highly* recommend using GSAP's [Install Helper](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Installation?checked=core,cssRule#modules) until you get comfortable with the importing/registering format.

Side note, you don't need to explicitly use the `css` object inside of tweens most of the time. GSAP detects that it's a DOM object and attempts to use the CSSPlugin if it recognizes it as a DOM object. `visibility` is also not an animatable property, so you should use a `.set()` instead:

```
tl.set(container.current, { visibility: "visible" })
.to(imageReveal, { duration: 1, cssRule: { width: "0%" }, ease: "power2.in" });
```

Note that you use the `cssRule` object to affect something obtained using `.getRule` Also note that I also used the condensed string form for the ease so you don't have to import that as well. It's better to use `scaleX` instead of `width` if you can because using `transform`s doesn't cause reflow like changing the element's width does.

[GSAP's docs](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/CSSRulePlugin) should be able to answer most questions like this going forward :)

Also note that we at GreenSock don't recommend using CSSRulePlugin in most cases. Instead we recommend animating actual elements (not pseudo-elements) or animating CSS variables.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a beginner with Greensock, so what do we need to register something like a CSSRulePlugin?

Comment: @LauraBeatris You just use the `registerPlugin` command after importing it as shown in my answer and the install helper.